# dojo Show/Hide One ContentPane While Another ContentPane Is Liquid

Tags: drop-down-menu, dojo, liquid-layout, border-container

I've been struggling for weeks trying to crack this nut so I'm not sure if it's impossible, or if it's my lack of coding chops... or both. I'm not a programmer and I'm a newbie to Dojo Toolkit.

I have a site using the BorderContainer layout. I'm trying to create an effect where I can use a button to open and close a dropdown type box that will contain controls. I need this dropdown to be hidden on page load, and then open when you click the button.

My problem is that when I open the dropdown, it pushes the content pane below it off the bottom of the browser window. I need the lower ContentPane to stay fit within the remaining space of the browser window when the dropdown opens. Additionally, I want the dropdown to sit outside of the scrollable container for the content below it, which is why I have it set up to sit outside a nested BorderContainer below it.

I've created a simplified version of the code to demonstrate my challenge (see link below). If you load the page you can see the center ContentPane scrolls the content. But, if you then click on the button, a dropdown div expands above the content. Then when you scroll, you'll notice that you can't see the full pane because it's in no-man's-land below the bottom of the browser window. I assume that because the div is set to display:none on load, it's size is not accounted for on page load. Then, when you open it by pressing the button, it's size is additive and the pane below doesn't know how to resize or account for the new element.

I've tried using the visibility attribute, but that leaves a gap for the div when it's still closed. I've tinkered with some code that controls the height that shows promise, but each of my dropdown boxes will be different sizes so I'd prefer that the height be set to "auto" rather than a specified pixel size.

Does anyone have any idea how I can accomplish this so that the lower pane will fit in the space without pushing off the screen?

Here's a sample of the page:

http://equium.com/scaffold.html

(I had some problems trying to insert the full HTML page here as a code sample so if that's a preferable way to handle it, and someone can let me know the best way to embed all of that code, I'd appreciate it.)

Thanks is advance, I'd really apprecaite anyone's feedback.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to take a look at `dojox.layout.ExpandoPane` (though be warned I think it has only worked properly for top and left regions for a while).

Also, I'd suggest simplifying/altering your layout a bit.  See example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/taFzv/

(It'd probably need some tweaking to get exactly what you want.)

The real issue you're having is probably that the BorderContainer has no idea that parts of the view resized.  ExpandoPane takes care of that by telling the BorderContainer to re-layout after its animation completes.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Ken. I will experiment with this and repost what I find. I haven't had a lot of success with the ExpandoPanes, but I'll admit I haven't worked very hard to properly understand how they work. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

It works under IE8.0.  When dropdown box open, just keep pressing mouse from page and drag to bottom, you could see the content was pushed to out of page. It looks the browser could  not detect it and could not add it to "scroll bar" account.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest taking out all BorderContainers except your top level one, the one with mainPage as the id.

Place your {stuff here} div into the mainPage BorderContainer, after the ContentPane with the Close/Open button.  Make sure you make it dojotype dijit.layout.ContentPane, set up layoutpriority, and set region to top.  Set the height to 0/x when clicking the Open/Close button, instead of setting display.

Try your page again.  If that doesn't fix it, you probably need, a call to layout, resize, or both to indicate to the BorderContainer that it needs to evaluate all its children and size the "center" pane properly.  Something like dijit.byId("mainPage").layout();  Do this any time someone presses the Close/Open button, after you have changed the height of any BorderContainer children.

Comment: Kevin, thank's for these ideas. I'll give both a try. The one trick with my "mainPage" container is that it actually holds more site structure that I excluded from this example just to demonstrate the problem. That doesn't necessarily invalidate your suggestion, it just explains why it appears that I have some unnecessary structure in this example.  I do think that your second recommendation might be what I have to do to get what I want. I'll post back my results after I do some testing. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the [dijit.form.DropDownButton](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dijit/form/DropDownButton.html) would fit your needs.  When click the button a tooltip is displayed that can be filled with any content you want.  Just as you specified, the dropdown tooltip is only displayed when you click the button, and it doesn't mess with the underlying layout at all.  The tooltip sits "on top" of the page.